# How to print specific row that contain specific word in bash

Tags: linux, bash

How can i print specific row if it contain specific word?

For example:

If from my output I'm receiving this list:

```
Name6 xxczvcv
Name5 zsadfsdf
Name2 dfsgsdfg
Name3 dgdfg
Name4  asdaa sd
```

And i want it to check if "Name2" is exist on the list, and if yes, print the row.

Thanks

Comment: Try: `man grep`

Comment: `grep "Name2" file_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the "grep" command.

e.g.

```
cat "fileContainingData" | grep "wordIAmLookingFor"
```

You should check out the [grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) for a better understanding of how it works and the options available.

Comment: Using `cat` with only one argument means something might be improvable... use `grep 'workIAmLookingFor' fileContainingData` instead.